# php: displaying titles and images of rss feed using xPath

Tags: php, xpath, rss, feed

I'm trying to get the titles and images of an rss feed to display using xpath in php. But it is only displaying 1 title. All the titles are not displaying and none of the images are getting displayed. My code:

```
function getImage($xml){
    $items=$xml->xPath('/rss/channel/item');
    foreach($items as $item){
        echo($item->title);
        $encl=$xml->xPath('//enclosure');
        print_r('<img src='.$encl->attributes()->url.'/>');
        echo('<br>');
    }
```

Can someone point out on where i'm going wrong? Thank you.

Comment: Provide a snippet of xml or point us to the rss feed so that we can answer this question.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got it to work. :) An image is displaying for each title. My code:

First, i'm downloading the rss feed using curl:

```
<?php
if (function_exists("curl_init")){
    $ch=curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'http://menmedia.co.uk/manchestereveningnews/news/rss.xml');
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    //curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER,0);
$data=curl_exec($ch);


curl_close($ch);


$doc=new SimpleXmlElement($data,LIBXML_NOCDATA);
```

Then i'm parsing the rss feed. Both method 1 and method 2 yields the same output.

```
function parseRSS($xml){
    $encl_array=array();
    $x=0;
    $i=0;

    $encls=$xml->xPath('/rss/channel/item/enclosure'); 
        foreach($encls as $encl) { 
            $encl_array[$x]=$encl->attributes()->url;
            $x+=1;
        }
            //method 1
    /*$cnt=count($xml->channel->item);
    for($i=0;$i<$cnt;$i++){
        $title=$xml->channel->item[$i]->title;
        print_r('<img src='.$encl_array[$i].'/>');
        echo $title.'<br>';
    }*/

            //method 2 - using xPath
    $items=$xml->xPath('/rss/channel/item');
    foreach ($items as $item){
        echo('<img src='.$encl_array[$i].'/>');
        echo($item->title.'<br>');
        $i+=1;
    }

}//end function parseRSS

    if (isset($doc->channel)) parseRSS($doc);
}//end if (function_exists("curl_init"))


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simply call it as

```
if($item->enclosure)
 print_r('<img src='.$encl->attributes()->url.'/>');
```